# How to break words at the end of line in text and quotes

Tags: line-breaking, margins, hyphenation, quotation

I would like LaTex to break words (where needed) at the end of a line - both in the main text and in quotes.

Having gone through similar questions, it sounds like LaTex normally does this automatically, so maybe I have somehow "turned it off" in my preamble.

Can anyone see, what the solution might be? I'm using Overleaf and compiling in pdfLaTex.

Photo of current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Q0I.png

Preamble and text example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

%%%% Packages
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\babeltags{ru=russian, en=english}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblo.bib}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=normal,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}\apptocmd\appendix{\pretocmd\section{\clearpage}{}{}}{}{}
\usepackage{subfiles} 

% Extra packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}\begin{spacing}{1}\oldquote}
  {\oldendquote\end{spacing}\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}}

% Commands
\setstretch{2.5}
\newcommand{\margmod}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.5}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\emph{#1}}}}

%%%% Layout style
\linespread{1.5}
\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \rightmark}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}

%%%% The document
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\small

In terms of the topic 'UK Politics' - the last of the four lowest-ranking topics I will focus on here -, the reason for this topic's low position is more difficult to determine, although the same argument as above can be the case again. In terms of UK politics, the qualitative examination of the topic revealed that most of the articles - unsurprisingly - were about Brexit, and as the following excerpt illustrate, the language again is not framed in any particular way:

\begin{quote}
\centering
The European Union's chief Brexit negotiator said on Monday that businesses still face the risk of a "cliff edge" Brexit at the end of the year, given the short time available to negotiate a future trading relationship between Britain and the EU. Michel Barnier told a joint news conference with Irish Prime Minister Leo Varadkar, Reuters quoted Barnier as saying. (RT, 28 January 2020) 
\end{quote}

\noindent
Actually, in none of the articles reviewed (those with the highest LDA score for topic 16), Russia was even mentioned. As before, this suggests that those articles about the UK - and the European Union for that sake (as there is no topic specifically about the European Union) - that also are related to Russia instead are captured by topic 17. That being said, the relatively low-ranking position of topic 17 below the middle in Figure X suggests that articles about 'Russia \& the EU' are not among the most important RT topics. In Figure X, on the other hand, the topic is positioned just above the mean value.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure your example is (1) minimal, (2) compilable (there is at least a `\end{document}` missing.

Comment: Unrelated: `\Huge` and friends does not take arguments.

Comment: Additionally you include files and gfx that we do not have access to so I'll add (3) The example should be self contained, that is don't refer to files not present in a standard LaTeX installation.

Comment: You should probably also have a look at the `csquotes` package as we do not use `"..."` for quotes in LaTeX. Often we use  \`\`...''  (which can be hard to type on a Danish keyboad, easier with `csquotes`)

Comment: Sure! I was afraid to leave something essential out, but I have updated a simpler, compilable code now.

Could you please elaborate on what the issue with the ´csquotes´ package is? Should I delete it? I don't need to use neither ". . ." or ``...'' for my quotes.

Comment: It is not an issue with it, it is your use of `"...."` (in the old version). Those are the wrong quotes. `\usepackage[english=topquotes]{csquotes}` might be better, and then use `\enquote{...}` to have proper quotation marks.

Comment: Unless you have been explicitly asked to do so, don't remove the paragraph indentation. It is there for a reason. \

Comment: Ah, get it know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `\centering` in your quote and `\raggedright` in the margin, both stop hyphenation as instead they add stretchy space either side of each line of text.

Comment: I see, thanks! Should I delete all of this line?: \newcommand{\margmod}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.5}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\emph{#1}}}}

Or only the words `\raggedright`?

Comment: @NicolaiMC if you use that command in the document (you do not use it in this example) just delete `\raggedright`  If you do not use it it doesn't matter what you do, but you may as well delete the whole definition

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!